# Throttling ChannelGroup in Netty

Tags: netty

There's `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler` that allows me to shape traffic for each `Channel`s and globally.

Is there a way of throttling a group of channels, for example captured in `ChannelGroup`?

So that I can have multiple `ChannelGroup`s and apply different throttling policy to each?

Comment: I've been doing some thinking.... if I could have multiple instances of `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler`, one per the channel group, I could then during the pipeline initialization add speficic instance based on say a host I am connecting to. So then "Global" would be accross all the channels that share given instance of `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler`... will that work? well only one way to find out